# Why is this command working only for every other line?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, zsh, xargs

When I run `\ls | xargs -I {} echo {} | sed 'N;s/\n/xxxxxxxxx/'`, I get this:

```
- Books aliasxxxxxxxxxA New Kind of Science
Computability-and-Logic.pdfxxxxxxxxxComputability-and-Logic_k2opt.pdf
Hein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005).pdfxxxxxxxxxHein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005)_k2opt.pdf
How Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users.pdfxxxxxxxxxHow Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users_k2opt.pdf
Lumanote- A Real-Time Interactive Music Composition Assistant.pdfxxxxxxxxxgeMsearch- Personalized Explorative Music Search.pdf
research_report_dc_02.pdfxxxxxxxxxresearch_report_dc_02_k2opt.pdf
thebookofshaders.pdfxxxxxxxxxthebookofshaders_k2opt.pdf
```

I don't understand why the output isn't this:

```
- Books aliasxxxxxxxxxA New Kind of SciencexxxxxxxxxComputability-and-Logic.pdfxxxxxxxxxComputability-and-Logic_k2opt.pdfxxxxxxxxxHein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005).pdfxxxxxxxxxHein J. L. - Prolog Experiments in Discrete Mathematics, Logic, and Computability (2005)_k2opt.pdfxxxxxxxxxHow Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users.pdfxxxxxxxxxHow Automated Recommendations Affect the Playlist Creation Behavior of Users_k2opt.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ seq 10  | sed 'N;s/\n/+/'
1+2
3+4
5+6
7+8
9+10
```

`N` adds the next line in the pattern space, then `s` joins those 2 lines with `+`, and then `sed` prints that line, and repeats the script for the next line of input (where lines 3 and 4 are joined with `+`... etc).

You'd need

```
$ seq 10 | sed 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/\n/+/g'
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
```

or use a loop a loop in your sed script to join all lines:

```
$ seq 10 | sed -e :1 -e '$!N;s/\n/+/;t1'
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
```

Note that it slurps the whole input into the pattern space which wouldn't scale well to large files.

To join lines with one character separator, you can use `paste`:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd + -
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10
```

For multi-character separator without loading the whole input in memory:

```
$ seq 10 | awk -v sep=-+- -vORS= 'NR>1 {print sep}; 1; END {if (NR) print RS}'
1-+-2-+-3-+-4-+-5-+-6-+-7-+-8-+-9-+-10
```

Comment: `seq 10 | gsed ':1;N;s/\n/+/;t1'` on macOS.

Comment: @HappyFace, I've updated it so it's compatible with macOS `sed` and POSIX compliant, `N` ran on the last line would exit without printing anything with macOS `sed` or GNU `sed` in POSIX mode.

Comment: @oliv, that's the point, it's to avoid outputting an empty line for an empty input.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sed` script with annotations:

```
# Append the next line of input to the pattern space with an embedded newline
N

# Replace the embedded newline with the string xxxxxxxxx
s/\n/xxxxxxxxx/

# (implicit print, start next cycle, overwriting the pattern space with the next line)
```

So, you read a line, append a line, substitute+output.  Then you read the third line, append the fourth, and substitute+output.

If you want to collect *all* lines, you can do that in two ways with `sed`.

1. Use an explicit loop:  `:top; N; $!btop; s/\n/xxxxxxxxx/g`, that is "append the next line, and if we're not yet at the end, do it again, then replace all newlines".
2. Use the hold space: `1{h;d;}; H; ${x;s/\n/xxxxxxxxx/g;p;}; d`, that is "copy the first line to the hold space and discard from the input, append all other line there too and delete them from the input, but when arriving at the last line, swap in the hold space, replace the newlines and print the result".

The main difference between these two alternatives is that the first never exits the first cycle until the very end and builds up the string in the pattern space, while the second runs to the end for each line of input and accumulates the result in the hold space.

---

Another way of looking at it, using `awk`.

Your `sed` code is essentially

```
awk '{ line = $0; getline; print line "xxxxxxxxx" $0 }'
```

What you want is

```
awk '{ line = (line == "" ? $0 : line "xxxxxxxxx" $0 ) } END { print line }'
```

This would simulate using the hold space in `sed`.

Or,

```
awk '{ line = $0; while (getline > 0) line = line "xxxxxxxxx" $0; print line }'
```

This would simulate using the explicit loop in `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because sed is processing line by line.
you have to make cycle like that: `sed -e ':again' -e 'N;s/\n/xxxxx/' -e 'tagain'`, or easier way is to use `tr "\n" "xxxxx"`

Comment: `tr` transliterates, it can only translate one character to one character not to a sequence of characters.